# Nav bar gradient using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to make the navigation bar color look like a fade? I'm pretty new to html and CSS which are the coding platforms I am using.

[something like this but for a navigation bar using html/CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uekza.png)

[image: The code I have for the navigation bar]

Comment: You want to change the `color` or `background-color`?

Comment: here you can make any desired gradient background - https://cssgradient.io/

Comment: Hey there, please add some code that you've worked on to make the question more clear. this could be achieved with HTML & CSS but we could help you if you share some more information.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would take a day for any response but 4 answers this fast.. Thank you so much. All the ones i tried worked

Comment: sorry i dont know how to make the box that shows the code. If someone can tell me how i can change it. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

In the image you linked, that's what is called a linear gradient (a gradual change in colour in a direction)

Here's a basic example:

```css
#navBar {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
}
```

```html
<ul id='navBar'>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
 </ul>
```

Here are some other examples:

```
linear-gradient(to right, #d4a72c, #d45c2c, #d43d2c);

linear-gradient(red, blue); //defaults red at the top, blue at the bottom

linear-gradient(25deg, red, blue); //25deg is angle of direction
```

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()

Answer (score 0):

background-image: linear-gradient(#5F0A87, #A4508B);

This should do the trick ;)

Comment: Thanks but i meant from left to right which i didnt specify. But for that i would just add (to left, #5F0383, #022B9D)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [linear-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient())

```css
nav {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #e66465, #9198e5);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it rather easily using css. There is a whole bunch of gradient functions available, the simplest of which being `linear-gradient()`. You can choose two (or more) colours, say blue and red, and set

```
background: linear-gradient('blue', 'red');
```

on your `nav` element. You can do all sorts of other things so maybe it is worth looking further at the `<gradient>` data-type. But this will certainly do what you indicated.